# telnet . Can't get hostname for your address

Tags: mysql, sql, ip, hostname, vds

i have a program that should work with the database (mysql). The database is on a dedicated server.

I want to connect to the database through Remote Desktop. I read that it is possible to check the entered

> telnet ip-dedicated-server 3306

On the old remote desktop it worked, but the new remote desktop when I try to connect to a database displays

> Can't get hostname from your ip address

**I found the solution**

in the mysql server configuration, my.ini or my.cnf , below

[mysqld]

add

skip-name-resolve

AND make restart mysql server

Comment: Just imagine, we are not sitting on your knees and observed what you are doing, nor do we know everything about your environment and try to explain it again in your question: What did you want to achieve? What are the participants in your try? What did you expect and for what reason did you expect it?

Comment: sorry, I have a program that should work with the database (mysql). On the old VDS, it worked, but on the new VDS when connecting to the database displays "Can't get hostname from your ip address"
I want to connect to the database through the VDS. I read that it is possible to input validation Telnet IP VDS 3306
I want to find solutions

Comment: And VDS stands for what again? To me it sounds like you have a problem with your reverse-DNS setup. What's the result of nslookup <ip of your new VDS>? btw: Try to edit your question and improve it instead of putting all the details in the comments. This might attract others to hand in an answer...

Comment: sorry, I changed the question

Comment: Perfect. Turned my down vote into an up vote as it is now a question that one can understand and you even proposed your own solution :-) One remark here: turing name-resolve off removes the ability of MySQL to check logins against a whitelist of hostnames, it only uses IP addresses instead: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/host-cache.html (3rd but last paragraph)